# Action class is throwing error Could not proxy

Tags: appium, appium-android

**Action class is throwing this error** .

```
Action action=null;
action=new Actions(android);    
action.moveToElement(melement).click().build().perform()
```

Error while clicking element/n

> Error is :An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the
>   command. Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy
>   command to remote server. Original error: 501 - "unimplemented
>   command: session/428b7e70ae59c02ea3bfb6da2f404581/actions"

JavaClient Version : `6.0.0 BETA4`

Appium : `1.10.0`

selenium-server: `3.9.0**`

Any idea what is causing this?

Below is my appium error log

```
[Chromedriver] UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while 
processing the command. Original error: unknown error: The adb command 
failed. Extra response: <001ddevice 'ZY2239MTHQ' not foundFAIL001ddevice 
offline (no transport)>.
[Chromedriver] (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
[Chromedriver] (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609545 
(c2f88692e98ce7233d2df7c724465ecacfe74df5),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64)
[Chromedriver] at errorFromMJSONWPStatusCode 
(/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-base- 
driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:789:10)
[Chromedriver] at ProxyRequestError.getActualError 
(/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-base- 
driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:683:14)
[Chromedriver] at JWProxy.command 
(/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-base- 
driver/lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:234:19)
```

Does this mean ADB is defective or my Device??

Answer (score 1):

First thing to consider when looking the logs, the log says `<001ddevice 'ZY2239MTHQ' not foundFAIL001ddevice offline (no transport)>.` which means that even if your device is connected to the machine, it's in offline state.

You can try reconnecting the device and check `adb devices`. This command must display device with it's current state.

Another point is, use Appium server and Java client which correspond to each other.

Appium Server `1.10` is supported by Java client `7.0`, and server `1.9.1` is supported by `6.1.0` Java client. So use these libraries accordingly.

Another point to notice here is you are using `Action` class instead of `AndroidTouchAction` in case of Android device and `IOSTouchAction` class in case of iOS device. So use proper class to see the results you desire.

Also consider using latest version of selenium jar as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use adb uninstall and remove this packages. This works for me:

```
adb -s UDID uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server
adb -s UDID uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
adb -s UDID uninstall io.appium.unlock
adb -s UDID uninstall io.appium.settings
```

OR

This issue can be caused because of timeout sometimes as well. Keep some sleep and see 
    after each action. If that works use proper waits.

Comment: UDID is the device ID which we get from adb devices??

Comment: Yes UDID us the device ID for IOS. In android it's device ID

Comment: adb uninstall <package_name> you can either do this, skipping the deviceID from above commands.

Comment: Still facing the same issue , do you have any other way to tackle this problem ? Thanks you for your time

Comment: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/11538 people found a solution for this here by downgrading the appium version or completely removing it and reinstalling it. Please follow the above thread.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are using **udid** in your **desiredCapabilities** with value ZY2239MTHQ. It is unable to find your device with udid ZY2239MTHQ. Make sure your device is connected properly.
Run following command in your terminal:

`adb devices`

This command will show the devices connected to your computer. If your device is not listed, you must enable the developer option in your device.

> Make sure the udid you use in your code match with the udid shown using above command.

Comment: adb devices shows the same Id, turns out that this behaviour is only occuring on a spevific element of a specific page of my AUT , every other element is getting clicked easily with the same method

Comment: Are you getting this error every time you are in this screen? Did your device screen turned off while your are executing the test? The error log is showing your device is offline.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the element that you want to navigate is not on the current page because the requested page is not loaded fast enough to load needed element before **click()** function is called or it just redirected to another page while your element still is not loaded. Try to put **wait()** function to wait your element for loading before **click()** function.

Comment: Element is present and is Visible